# Release the new android bundle version after uploading to Google play console REST API

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, devops, cicd

Im trying to setup up CI/CD from build an application to deploy to google play.
My steps:

1. I make the request for getting edit_id with Method: **edits.insert**
2. Then I upload bundle with Method: **edits.bundles.upload**
3. Then I update the track to Production with Method: **edits.tracks.update**
4. After all of that steps I commit the edit with Method: **edits.commit** and expect to see the new version of application in the Releases overview in Google play console.
   But I did not find it there. There are unfinished steps to make the release manualy by GUI. I need to push **Edit release** button, then press to **Add from library** and make a choise my bundle.

My question:
How can I automatize making release with REST API? I Would apriciate for any advice.

I could not find any methods for release of uploaded bundle in this REST documentation **https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest**

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question. The body of request was not correct in the Method: **edits.tracks.update**. It should be like this

```
    {
     "track": "production",
     "releases": [
    {
      "versionCodes": [MY_VERSION],
      "status": "completed"
    }
  ]
}
```